# Timeline overview of implemented Mathematica functions

Tags: date-and-time, built-in-symbols, charts

With

```
WolframLanguageData[{"ListLogPlot", "Plot", "ColorNegate"}, "Timeline"]
```

one gets information at what time and version a certain function was implemented:

[image]

UPDATE:

`Show` is a good idea as long as the functions were not introduced at the same time.

```
p1 = WolframLanguageData[{"Plot"}, "Timeline"];
p2 = WolframLanguageData[{"Sin"}, "Timeline"];
Show[p1, p2]
```

Here the function labels overlap:

[image]

Do you have an idea how a larger set of commands can be visualized in one diagram?

E.g.:

```
functions = {"Sin", "Cos", "Tan", "Image", "ImageApply", "Array"};
```

How can I make a timeline (with `Show` or somehow else) with no overlap?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried `Show`? Do you know how to make a combined timeline from scratch using the raw data, or would you need help with that should no other solution exist?

Comment: @C. E. see Update ...

Comment: Use something like `WolframLanguageData[{"ListLogPlot", "Plot", 
  "ColorNegate"}, {"DatesModified", "VersionsModified"}]` then parse it out using `TimelinePlot[Labeled[Interval[], ....]` you can modify the spacing and like or use legends.

Comment: @Ramble: Can you show the exact solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
versionData=WolframLanguageData[{"ListLogPlot", "Plot", "ColorNegate","Sin"}, {"Name", "DateIntroduced", "DateLastModified","VersionIntroduced", "VersionLastModified"}]

partTimeLine = Partition[#, 3] & /@ versionData

TimelinePlot[Labeled[Interval[#[[2 ;; 3]]], #[[1]]] & @@@ partTimeLine]
```

You can then add in the version numbers in the same fashion. You will probably need to fiddle manually or use a legend to deconflict tiled labels. Or you can increase the partition to include the versions

```
partTimeLine = Partition[#, 5] & /@ versionData
```

Then change

```
TimelinePlot[Labeled[Interval[#[[2 ;; 3]]], #[[1]]<>ToString[#[[{4, 5}]]]] & @@@ partTimeLine]
```

[image]

[image]

To label line and place version numbers at each end:

```
TimelinePlot[
 Labeled[Interval[#[[2 ;; 3]]], #[[{1, 4, 5}]], {Bottom, Left, 
     Right}] & @@@ partTimeLine]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice solution ... how would you show the version number?

Comment: Thanks. Edited it to include the version number.

Comment: Or do the same as WolframLanguageData:
`TimelinePlot[
 Labeled[Labeled[
   Interval[{DateObject[{2003, 4, 28}], DateObject[{2013, 3, 1}]}], 
   "a"], {"b", "c"}, {Before, After}]]`

Answer (score 2):

I think `GraphicsColumn` is what you are looking for.

```
functions = {"Sin", "Cos", "Tan", "Image", "ImageApply", "Array"};
plots = WolframLanguageData[functions, "Timeline"];
GraphicsColumn[plots]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: I wanted to see everything in one timeline ...